# Can neural network predict outcomes based on patterns which arent in its training set

Tags: neural-network, artificial-intelligence

This may sound like an open ended question and I apologize in advance. I know that a neural network can predict the outcome based on the patterns found in training data set. Can a neural network predict outcomes based on patterns which it hasnt observed. If not then what sort of algorithm should be used for handling such a problem.

Comment: Machine-learning can only build a model based on your data and some assumptions you add with your algorithms/preprocessings and co. So it can't learn patterns not found within these sources. But the question is: what are patterns and which patterns ML does recognize (e.g. you might see these patterns as curves in some image; ML might *see* these as something else after some transformations / or due to internal processing which might help learning more and much different patterns you recognize).The information-theoretic view: without seeing these patterns, you got no info about how to handle th

Answer (score 1):

Most neural network applications operate on the basis of supervised learning, which means that the algorithm is given feedback regarding its performance. The algorithm uses the feedback to adjust network weights. The most common mechanism for this adjustment is back-propagation, but there are others.

**Training Set vs Training Signal.**

Your question mentions a training set. However, the fact that neural networks require feedback does not necessarily imply the existence of a training set, that is just one alternative. Sometimes feedback can sometimes be sensed directly from the environment in which the network is operating.

Examples of feedback without a training set:

(1) Imagine a neural network that is being trained to robotically balance a pole. The feedback might come from accelerometer data and, ultimately, success or failure at each balancing task.

(2) Imagine a neural network that is being trained to optically recognise characters. Large training sets *are* available for this purpose. But, the feedback could also come from comparison with human performance or with the output of another OCR technology.

Nevertheless, whether or not there is a training *set*, there is still a training *signal*. Speaking generally, neural networks are not effective at *prediction* in the absence of a training signal (but more on that later).

**Hebbian Learning.**

The starting point for neural network learning in the absence of a training signal is Hebbian learning. Hebb's postulate is:

> When an axon of cell A is near enough to excite cell B or repeatedly
>   or consistently takes part in firing it, some growth or metabolic
>   change takes place in one or both cells such that A's efficiency, as
>   one of the cells firing B, is increased.

The internet has pithily summed this up as "cells that fire together, wire together." If you are interested you could look at the work of Linsker and von der Malsburg. Their research involved the emergence of self-organisation in the visual cortex and is primarily motivated by biology.

**Vector Quantisation.**

Even if a training signal is not available, there are algorithms that can generate meaningful insight into data. This insight might take the form of classification rather than predication. For example, an algorithm could divide input into n groups, but it could not say whether members of any particular group are *better* or *worse* than the other: just that they are different. This is termed 'cluster analysis'. Perhaps the most successful such algorithm is vector quantisation.

A common approach used in unsupervised learning is competitive learning. Instead of responding to a training signal, the algorithm compete within itself to make sense of data. An example of such a strategy is winner-takes-all in which the strongest firing neuron is presumed to be the most successful.

**Self-Organising Feature Maps**

Coming back to neural networks, there is a neural network algorithm that operates under unsupervised learning to perform cluster analysis. This is the self-organising feature map (SOFM), also called a Kohonen map. The SOFM uses competitive learning to train a neural network.

[image: By Denoir - Using my own software, CC BY-SA 3.0, https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?curid=40452073]
Figure. A self-organising map of Wikipedia. (Attribution: By Denoir - Using my own software, CC BY-SA 3.0, https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?curid=40452073)

In SOFMs, proximity implies similarity.

To return to the question, neither vector quantisation nor SOFMs require a training set or a training signal. Even so, these algorithms are able to identify patterns in data (see Figure).

Comment: This is a great reply but I don't think it directly answers the original question: can neural nets make predictions based on data they haven't seen?

Comment: Thanks, I've edited the answer to try to make it more concrete about that. I guess the real issue here is that NNs are not really in the business of prediction, they're in the business of classification. I may need to come back to that point again.

Comment: Let me explain what I thought could be done. An algorithm that supervises the working of neural network might provide random inputs to the neural network (sort of brute force) and then cluster the results to make a more comprehensive sense of the possibilities that could be analyzed by this neural network... And eventually this supervisory sort of algorithm which is purely (if -else based) would redefine the neural network to include more neurons and more connections. Would such sort of system predict patterns which it hasn't learned by training set/signal .?

Comment: @user3693606. I'm not sure it works like that, the question is how would the supervisor refine the network in the absence of a training signal? I wonder if you are thinking on the same lines as "neuroevolution" in which the topology of the network evolves under evolutionary pressure. Check out Kenneth O. Stanley's NEAT algorithm (there are others too). Those networks evolve some surprisingly subtle characteristics without the final topology having to be known in advance. For example, see: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5lJuEW-5vr8

Answer (score 1):

The question which you ask is really wide and ambiguous and in my opinion there is no one true answer to it. It depends on the topology of your network, the nature of your data and on how learning process was performed. I think that you may consider different separate cases:

1. **New pattern is possible to be inferred out of examples from learning dataset:** in this case your network **could** be able to recognize new pattern and classify it correctly. To understand the issue try imagine the following case: your data has two features: price and quality. In your data you have examples of *low price - low quality, low price - high quality, high price - low quality* patterns but you don't have examples of *high price - high quality* examples and you expect your network to provide good results. The answer to the question if it is possible depends of the nature of your problem. If e.g. price is the most important your network will probably qualify new samples properly. But if the pattern is more subtle - then it might be completely random. Note that with more subtle pattern you should also take into account what kind of features your network extracted from original data. If for example *price* and *quality* features are not provided but they might be inferred from other data - your network could not extract it at all if they are not need for solving original classification task.
2. **New pattern is independent of patterns from an original dataset:** in this case I would rather expect your network to perform poorly on new data.

As you can see the answer to your question is not straightforward and it depends on nature of your data and the problem you want to solve. For the same reason I think that if you want to look for different algorithms to manage with your task - you need to specifiy more details about your problem.